# ¿Cómo relleno un input por medio de un select con laravel?

Tags: laravel, select, input

hola amigos quisiera llenar un input con un precio al momento de seleccionar un habitación. Es decir que si selecciono la habitación 1 me aparezca el valor de la habitación en un input al momento de seleccionarlo, agradezco su ayuda.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-half">
            <p class="text-white text-center">Habitaciones disponibles</p>
            <div class="input-group">
                <select name="habitacion" class="@error('habitacion') is-invalid @enderror" id="habitacion">
                    <option value="">----- Seleccione una opción -----</option>

                    <!-- Se recorren todas las habitaciones disponibles -->
                    @foreach($habitacion as $habitacion)
                        <option value="{{ $habitacion->id }}" {{ old('habitacion') == $habitacion->id ? 'selected' : '' }} >Habitación {{$habitacion->n_habitacion}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

                @error('habitacion')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-half">
            <p class="text-white text-center">Valor de la habitación</p>
            <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
                <input type="text" name="precio" class= " @error('precio') is-invalid @enderror" id="precio" placeholder="Precio de la habitación" disabled>
                                
                @error('precio')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
                <div class="input-icon">
                    <img src="{{asset('img/dollar.png')}}" class="d-inline" width="22" height="22">
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Necesitas ajax, te recomiendo investigues al respecto, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: que tantos registros son, si no son muchos puedes hacerlo sin necesidad de ajax, solo con js, que tanta data tienes y te podria ayudar

Comment: @NicolasAldana pues es un seeder con 19 campos los cuales contienen el precio de la habitación, lo único es que nunca he manejado js  :c